# Setting Associated IDs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image that `belongs_to` a user and to a binary (physical file attributes are stored in a separate model). In the old days (read: yesterday), I set the user_id value manually:

```
@image = Image.new( params[:image] )
@image.user_id = current_user
```

A friend recently clued me in to the fact that I should use associations instead, so my controller code became:

```
@image = current_user.image.new( params[:upload] )
```

That, of course, is much nicer and works great. Now I'd like to do something similar for my binary association, but I don't know how. Extracting and storing my binary is done by a `BinaryObserver` class that observes the `Image` model. In the observer's `before_validation` callback, the uploaded file is sent to the `Binary` class and and a binary object is created/stored. Once stored, I need to set the `binary_id` value for my image model. I've been doing that the manual way, but I now feel like I should be doing it the other way.  Here's what I have in `BinaryObserver#before_validation`:

```
def before_validation( model )
  binary          = Binary.new.upload( model.upload ) rescue raise
  binary          = binary.store()
  model.binary_id = binary.id
rescue => e
  #
  # Rethrow any exception that was raised.
  #
  raise
end
```

Should I be doing this the other way? If so, how? In a multiple association scenario, I can't see a way to set more than one foreign key value "automagically".

Thanks.

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the right answer. Instead of setting a variable to hold the newly created `Binary` instance, I set the association itself:

```
model.binary = Binary.new.upload( model.upload ) rescue raise
```

That seems to do exactly what I was after. It sets the foreign key value automatically and also allows me to being acting on the associated object directly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have a has_one/belongs_to relationship for Image/Binary?  That might be of use as well...

Comment: I do. An Image belongs_to a Binary and a Binary has_one Image.